# CSS based framework like SCSS (Adaptive design)

Tags: iphone, html, css, sass

I am designing a web app from scratch, which would be a fluid-based layout and the same HTML would render on different screens using the adaptive CSS.
I am going to use adaptive CSS (or responsive design) for this.

I was looking to use a framework like SCSS (http://sass-lang.com/) which would improve my code maintenance efforts. I'll have lots of CSS files (and probably some skin based as well)
Since I am using adaptive layout, I am going to use CSS Media Queries for desktop/tablet/mobile CSS. I could not get an idea how well the SCSS would integrate with media queries and overall speaking , how much flexibility will it offer to me.

Please let me know your suggestions if you have used SASS/SCSS and in general, any other suggestions.

Comment: frameworks are for lazy people

Comment: DID YOU EVEN UNDERSTAND THE QUESTION, BEFORE DOWNVOTING ?

Comment: lol. I did not downvote it mate. Have a look at my profile. I have 0 downvotes

Comment: +1 beacuse this is democracy, not demagogery

Comment: lol. This is beacoming a downvote war despite the fact that I did not downvote you. Infact I upvoted your question. What are you trying to do. Find my old posts and downvote them all - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926580/html-comments-inside-opening-tag-of-the-element - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926769/web-accessibility

Comment: Ok..no worries..reverted..Actually u need to edit first..

Comment: dont care one way or other. Still think frameworks are for lazy people. HTML and CSS is too simple for them to have frameworks. Looking at any HTMl or CSS framework, you will find extra markup that is present there without any semantics. This is the first reason we ditched table based layouts in teh first place. With frameworks we are just repeating a decade old mistake again!

Comment: For the record, SCSS/Sass is not a framework.

Comment: @Jawad actually, html/css itself could be considered a framework, ie: a default set of entities that can be implemented to a custom requirement. I don't use frameworks like 960 often but if I build a large project, I'll roll my own framework so it scales quickly and reliably. Ironically, the misconception that frameworks are for lazy people is an outdated idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCSS is essentially an extension to CSS, and is useful (with mixins) to void repetition in your code. It also provides a way to group blocks of CSS in semantically meaningful ways and gives you variables to avoid repeating yourself.

If you are using a framework such as Rails, it is no-brainer.

There are also frameworks which focus on layout such as 960 (and its variants), and Blueprint which also adds code for thing like buttons.

The underlying philosophy behind many of these is DRY (don't repeat yourself). One bonus of using an established framework is that many of the browser issues have been ironed out, so you can be sure that it will work cross-browser.

It is true that perhaps the code is not quite a lean as rolling your own, but with careful editing and making sure you minify the result and send it gzipped, this is not a major issue except on the most high traffic sites.

Personally I have objected to using frameworks in the past because of the small amount of additional redundant code, but after 15 years of hacking around browser issues, I now think they are a Good Thing.

Larry Wall said in Programming Perl, "We will encourage you to develop the three great virtues of a programmer: laziness, impatience, and hubris."

Anything that allows more people to use CSS in a repeatable and reliable way, to build on work done by other, and to try out some of the leading edge features has got be a good thing.

Engineering a site with media queries is still a bit leading edge. There are compromises in each approach and you should read up as much as possible before choosing one. Adapt.js is a good alternative if you don't mind javascript.

You may want to look into the HTML5 Boilerplate. This has some useful defaults, and lots of documentation about the HTML and CSS defaults that have been chosen.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have not used media queries together with SCSS, but I don't think they conflict with each other. I have used SCSS extensively in my current rails apps, and it helped me to reduce the amount of code, and get a better understanding when to use which styles.

The tricky part will be what to have fluid (changing depending on the medias viewport size), and how to avoid repetition.

Have a look at the nice site [Responsive Design with CSS3 Media Queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries), to get an idea which parts of your layout may be fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [320+Susy](http://susy-media.oddbird.net/static/susy320/) ([GitHub repo here](https://github.com/ericam/320-susy)). It uses the [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) grid framework extension for [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). All of these tools are based on Sass and make use of media queries.